# Reducing Bit Order Logic

Tags: c#, logic, bit, flags

I have the following code, and I'm wondering if there's a more succinct, reduced way to write this code:

(FontStyle is a .NET Enum with the Flags attribute)

```
lblPrompt.Font.Style = FontStyle.Regular;

if (chkBold.Checked)
    lblPrompt.Font.Style |= FontStyle.Bold;
if (chkItalics.Checked)
    lblPrompt.Font.Style |= FontStyle.Italic;
if (chkUnderline.Checked)
    lblPrompt.Font.Style |= FontStyle.Underline;
```

I have a feeling the answer lies in correctly applying the and & operator between CheckBox.Checked and the desired flag, similar to the following:

```
lblPrompt.Font.Style =
    (chkBold.Checked & FontStyle.Bold)
    | (chkItalics.Checked & FontStyle.Italic)
    | (chkUnderline.Checked & FontStyle.Underline);
```

This does not work however because the compiler apparently does not like my direct application of the ampersand with a bool and a Flag/Enum type.

Comment: The first snippet is clear and easy to reason about. I wouldn't change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something along these lines:

```
lblPrompt.Font.Style |=
    (chkBold.Checked ? FontStyle.Bold : 0)
    | (chkItalics.Checked ? FontStyle.Italic : 0)
    | (chkUnderline.Checked ?  FontStyle.Underline : 0);
```

Comment: Is that any more efficient than the previous attempt?  It is more succinct, which is what the OP was after, I think, but I'm wondering if it is faster.  I only ask because we're dealing with bitwise manipulation.

Comment: The assignment (`=`) should be an OR (`|=`) to match the original behavior.

Comment: @BlackVegetable I think the OP only cared about brevity. Though, I personally don't think it's more readable than the original code.

Comment: This solution works, although you must precede it with the following: ( lblPrompt.Font.Style = FontStyle.Regular ) otherwise it will simply add new flags, not "reset" them to the state of the UI controls. I was really hoping for a solution that allows me to "set" the flags without having to preset the variable to zero, for brevity sake.

Comment: @MartinBliss well, you can assign `FontStyle.Regular = 0` in your enum. Then it is the default value when doing bit logic.

Comment: @Shedal I don't understand what you mean. It sounds like you're saying the same thing I just said: That you have to set the enum to 0 BEFORE the code in your original answer, because the code given only "adds" flags, and doesn't "set" them.

Comment: @Martin I was referring to the possibility of manually assigning numerical values for the flags while defining the enum. Like, Regular=0, Bold=1, and so on. In that case, "no flags" already means "Regular". But maybe I misunderstood what you're missing in the solution.

Comment: @Shedal What I mean is that, given an enum I can't modify (it's not my enum), I have to set the value of an enum variable to 0 before executing your line of code, otherwise I will simply get the previous value AND any new flags set. For example: If the initial value of lblprompt.Font.Style is FontStyle.Italic, and I have Bold and Underline checked, the result (with your code) is all three. If I set to zero prior to your code, I will get Bold and Underline, NOT Italic... the expected behavior. I was hoping to avoid having to set the initial flag as a matter of code style.

Comment: @MartinBliss just use `lblPrompt.Font.Style =` instead of `lblPrompt.Font.Style |=`.

Comment: @Shedal I don't know why I didn't think of that! I'm pretty sure I tried it once and it didn't work, but it works now so I guess I made a mistake before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can think of would be to use the ternary operator, like the following:

```
lblPrompt.Font.Style = FontStyle.Regular
             | (chkBold.Checked      ? FontStyle.Bold      : FontStyle.Regular)
             | (chkItalics.Checked   ? FontStyle.Italic    : FontStyle.Regular)
             | (chkUnderline.Checked ? FontStyle.Underline : FontStyle.Regular);
```

similarly indenting similar portions of expressions is a stylistic thing that I do and you are by no means obligated to carry it into your own code.

Comment: Similar to Shedal's answer, this doesn't ensure that `FontStyle.Regular` bits, if any, are set when all of the boxes are checked.  It should either use `|=` or toss `FontStyle.Regular | ` in.

Comment: I fixed it to always set FontStyle.Regular.

Answer (score 0):

If you have significantly more options than just those three, it might be worth doing a table-driven solution:

```
var table = new [] {
        new { box = chkBold, style = FontStyle.Bold },
        new { box = chkItalics, style = FontStyle.Italic },
        new { box = chkUnderline, style = FontStyle.Underline }
    };

foreach(var combo in table)
{
  if(combo.box.Checked) 
        lblPrompt.Font.Style |= combo.style;        
}
```

This is not necessarily more *concise*, but it keeps you from repeating yourself.

Comment: You can also make it a `Dictionary<bool, FontStyle>`.

Comment: Indeed, anything that can hold all the data works. I just like the names of anonymous classes.